# In Bonanza: Gangsters, can the mafia steal more than one card during phase 4?

Tags: bohnanza

In Bonanza: Gangsters, the mafia can steal cards during phase 4.  You pick 3 cards, and if they match a mafia's bean field, they take that card.

The rules state that if the bean drawn matches a mafia's bean field, they take it and you immediately draw a card to replace it.  If that card *also* matches a mafia's bean field, is it also taken?

I ask because in the next rule, regarding pulling cards from the discard pile, the rules are very explicit about repeating the process until the top discard card no longer matches the currently drawn card.  They are not as clear for the mafia rules.

Comment: My group played it with the Mafia taking the replacements if they matched and continuing to draw until either the Mafia had to harvest or the bean was different.  Not sure if this question was asked before or after your other question about phase 4.  Maybe that makes the rule seem better now?